# Discord.js chinese characters appearing as boxes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a bot, it displays information, which includes names. Often these names are entirely/include Chinese characters. Whenever they do, they are converted into boxes or random characters. This sorta break the bot completely as it means you cant tell what box box symbol box means. I assume this is not only Chinese characters, I just haven't come across any others so far.

Looked it up on google, different phrases but found nothing even related to it on discord.js.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Low quality and small ik..
[image: IK the image is low quality... But you can see what i mean from it]

Comment: More "terrible colors" (protip: if you absolutely need to use screenshots of text, change your theme first), but it's clear enough: that's just classic "utf-8 text getting rendered by something that isn't set to utf-8".

Comment: Would it have anything to do with my version of nodejs? Or would it be between the code and the discord.js api?

Comment: the absolute first candidate would be "does the page declare `<meta charset="utf-8">` so that the browser actually decodes text properly?"

Comment: Where does the mojibake occur? Does it only occur in the terminal? Or are sent messages affected as well?

Comment: The send messages appear like this.